# how to make excel window open after connecting to the book?

Tags: xlwings

wb1 = xw.Book('C:\Users\89378\Desktop\12345.xlsx')

when I run this code ,the excel window does not open. But I can find the excel running in the backgroud in the windows task manager. How can I fix this,making the excel window open in the front.
really thanks.

Comment: wb1 = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\89378\Desktop\12345.xlsx')

Comment: forgot to use the raw string in the original question

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your app `visible`.

```
app = xw.App(visible=True)
```

[Python API](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#app):

> **visible (bool, default None)** – Returns or sets a boolean value that determines whether the app is visible. The default leaves the state unchanged or sets visible=True if the object doesn’t exist yet.